# Jboss RestEasy web service connection pooling

Tags: resteasy, jboss-eap-6

Getting error 
        NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.(Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;Lorg/apache/http/conn/DnsResolver;)

Using httpclient-4.2-alpha1.jar

Configuration :

```
<!--  Rest easy connection pooling  -->
<bean id="poolingClientConnectionManager" class="com.auction.acp.rest.impl.ConnectionManager" >
</bean>
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" >
    <constructor-arg name="conman" ref="poolingClientConnectionManager">  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When I explore jar this constructor is already there. 
First thing which is coming in my mind is some other library [I'm using JBoss] is in use.
Tried with exclusions in jboss-deployment-structure.xml but no luck.

```
<exclusions>
    <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
    <module name="org.apache.http.impl.conn" />
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor exists in the JAR you're "exploring" but JBoss can't find it, it means JBoss is not using the JAR you want it to. I suggest using Logback for logging, as it'll add the name of the JAR to the stacktrace in your logs so you know which JAR JBoss is using.